# Terminal "find" command not working

Tags: gnome-terminal

Ok, so my terminal was working fine yesterday, but all of a sudden, it decided that no file or directory exists anymore. This is what happens:

```
seabass@seabass:~$ find /home/seabass/Documents hello

/home/seabass/Documents

/home/seabass/Documents/test

/home/seabass/Documents/test/hello

find: `hello': No such file or directory
```

and:

```
seabass@seabass:~$ find /home/seabass/Documents test

/home/seabass/Documents

/home/seabass/Documents/test

/home/seabass/Documents/test/hello

find: `test': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you read the man page?

Answer (score 1):

Is not working because you are doing in the wrong way. Try:

```
find /home/seabass/Documents/hello
```

respective:

```
find /home/seabass/Documents/test
```

Or:

```
find /home/seabass/Documents -name hello
```

respective:

```
find /home/seabass/Documents -name test
```

See `man find` and `find --help` for more informations.

Comment: oh, thanks, i thought i might just be not doing it right

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-name` parameter. It thinks you want it to search for files **inside** `hello` or `test`, but I'm guessing that's not what you want.

```
find /home/seabass/Documents -name hello
```